# How to Stop a thread in C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, class, methods

I have created a **simple C# Form application** and there is another class  **Mouse_Tracking.cs**

When I click **start button**, thread **start and works fine**. but when I click **stop button** **Nothing happens**

> Could you please help me to fix the issue of fallowing code. :( :( :(

***here the code of Mouse_Tracking class.***

```
public class Mouse_Tracking
    {
        public int flag = 1;

        public void run()
        {
            while (flag == 1)
            {
                //Do Something
            }
    }
```

*Here the code of **start button***

```
private void btn_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var mst = new Mouse_Tracking();

        Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(mst.run));

        thread1.Start();
    }
```

*Here the code of **Stop button***

```
 private void btn_stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var mst = new Mouse_Tracking();

            mst.flag = 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not setting the flag of the object you created in btn_start_Click. Instead you create a new `Mouse_Tracking` object and set its value. Use the same instance....

For ex;

declare it as

```
Mouse_Tracking mst = new Mouse_Tracking();

private void btn_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mst = new Mouse_Tracking();
    .......
}

private void btn_stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     mst.flag = 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried to use same object. but I couldn't. Could you please help me to use same object in both button clicks ?

Comment: For future reference, if you ever need to stop all threads in a project you are debugging, you can always use the Debug --> Terminate All option in Visual Studio.  If it isn't showing up in your Debug droplist as an option, you can add it to the Debug menu by going into Tools --> Customize and going to the Commands tab.